# What doe the meaning of font-size:1em/2em?

Tags: css, frontend

In some templates I see some developers use `font-size` property look like this:

`font-size:1em/2em` 

What does it mean ?

 I think the 1em is `min-font-size` and 2em is `max-font-size`

 Is it true ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this:

Use:

```
font: 1em/1.5em bold italic serif;
```

instead of

```
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.5em;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
font-family: serif;
```

it's CSS shorthand properties

Comment: Thank you @AramMkrtchyan but you use font property while I said font-size!

Comment: ok :D you cant write font-size:1em/2em  it's not correct; it's work with font:

Comment: :| Really ?!! But what I saw before ? :-? Thank's :D

Comment: I don't know, but i specially test your code and it incorrect. i never see code like that i see only with font:

Answer (score 0):

When the units are specified in em or ex, the size is defined relative to the size of the font on the parent element. For example, 0.5em is half the font size of the parent of the current element. Referred https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size